# How to split a string from an object in an array into new objects in the array

Tags: arrays, object, split, dataweave, mule4

We have the below input which has an address field with colon as value. This need to be considered as a new object.
Input:

```
{
 "Customer" : [
  {
   "name": "abc",
   "age": 23,
   "address": "test4"
  },
  {
   "name": "xyz",
   "age": 28,
   "address": "test:mule"
  },
  {
   "name": "pqr",
   "age": 25,
   "address": "test1"
  }
 ]
}
```

Expected Output considering colon in field:

```
{
 "Customer" : [
  {
   "name": "abc",
   "age": 23,
   "address": "test4"
  },
  {
   "name": "xyz",
   "age": 28,
   "address": "test"
  },
 {
   "name": "xyz",
   "age": 28,
   "address": "mule"
  },
  {
   "name": "pqr",
   "age": 25,
   "address": "test1"
  }
 ]
}
```

If we have colon in the field address then that needs to be updated as a different object.

Comment: This looks like `JSON`. If it is, use a `JSON` library to handle this data.

Comment: The original title was confusing. I changed it to be more specific.

Comment: you are right @aled, that was good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the below DataWeave Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
 Customer: payload.Customer flatMap ((item, index) -> do {
      var codes = item.address splitBy ":"
      ---
      codes map {
        "name": item.name,
        "age": item.age,
        "address": $
      }
    })
```

below is the screenshot with input, script, and required output
[image]

Comment: Thank you Anurag, its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
Customer: flatten(payload.Customer map (
     ($.address splitBy ":") map (item,index) -> ($ - "address" ++ {address: item })
 
))
```